# Appium - @FindBy does not identify element - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

creating a page factory setup in Appium, the script cannot detect elements on screen.

So far tried:

1. Changing AndroidDriver to AppiumDriver
2. Swapping between @AndroidFindBy and @FindBy

Here are details of code:

**1: Initial class** (Note - Global Setup has all the desired capabilities and driver initiation)

```
public class TC01_HomePage extends GlobalSetup {

    @Test
    public void HomePages() throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {   
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = GlobalSetup.Capabilities();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    WelcomePageObjects welcome = new WelcomePageObjects(driver);
    welcome.verifyWelcomePage();        
    }
}
```

**2: This is how WelcomePageObjects class looks like**

```
public class WelcomePageObjects {
    
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    
    public WelcomePageObjects(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) 
    {
        this.driver = (AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>)driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }
    
    //Registration Button
    @FindBy(xpath="//android.widget.TextView[@text='Register']")
    private AndroidElement registerBtn;


public void verifyWelcomePage()
    {
        Assert.assertTrue(registerBtn.isDisplayed());
    }
```

**3: This is uiautomatorview of the element**
[image]

**4: This is the Eclipse error**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: By.xpath: //android.widget.TextView[@text='Register']
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:126)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:59)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b598166c.isDisplayed(<generated>)
    at app.pom.pages.WelcomePageObjects.verifyWelcomePage(WelcomePageObjects.java:88)
    at Android.APPII.TC01_HomePage.HomePages(TC01_HomePage.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction@517566b (tried for 1 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:304)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.waitFor(AppiumElementLocator.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:119)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DELL-PC', ip: '192.168.1.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: com.appii.SplashActivity , appPackage: com.appii, automationName: uiautomator2, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appActivity: com.appii.SplashActivity , appPackage: com.appii, automationName: uiautomator2, deviceName: Android Device, platformName: android}, deviceApiLevel: 29, deviceManufacturer: samsung, deviceModel: SM-A750F, deviceName: 3200fe04ba2c95cf, deviceScreenDensity: 420, deviceScreenSize: 1080x2220, deviceUDID: 3200fe04ba2c95cf, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, pixelRatio: 2.625, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 10, statBarHeight: 63, takesScreenshot: true, viewportRect: {height: 2031, left: 0, top: 63, width: 1080}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 36bfeb30-8630-44b3-b6d5-61ecaa6029d3
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.widget.TextView[@text='Register']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:151)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:57)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.ContentMappedBy.findElement(ContentMappedBy.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:57)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.lambda$0(AppiumElementLocator.java:120)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:172)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: Have tried `//*[@text='Register']`?

Comment: @frianH, yes tried that and other combinations also. I don't know why the objects are not getting read, its happening for couple others also.


Guess I would have to work with the developers to get "resource-id" updated for the elements. This seems the best case solution because in several other elements also I'm using class with index as locator and that won't be viable as the application scales.

Thank you for your help!!